# Should we have a version 6 specific PowerShell tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Version 6 of PowerShell is significantly different from every prior version.

Unless I am completely missing it there is not currently a V6 specific tag. I believe that there should be one. The adoption at first I suspect will be spotty and often wrong, but as more people start using V6 I believe that it will be helpful.

Comment: there are [tag:powershell-v1.0] till [tag:powershell-v5.0]  so I see no reason to not continue with that tagging for V6. Just find a question that is specific about v6, add the tag and provide a non-plagiarized excerpt and wiki.

Comment: I will give some time for discussion then do that. To be honest personally I would want to roll every pre v6 question into one tag since they are all effectively one version when compared to V6 but I know that is probably too aggressive. :)

Comment: Yes, that would be too aggressive. :-P PowerShell 2 is still significant on its own as a baseline because later PowerShells can emulate it (using `-version 2`). 3, 4, 5 less so, but each of them introduced syntax changes where it's relevant to know what version a question is about to quickly exclude problems with trivial syntax errors (otherwise the tediously obvious "what version of PowerShell are you using" comment is necessary every time). Given that upgrading PowerShell is not always an option, having version tags is eminently useful.

Comment: I understand the argument against rolling them all in together that is why I did not ask for that and it is just a question. I find that most of the time even if there is a specific version tag I still have to have them verify what version they are on. For that matter the poster will often put more than one version tag on the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is [already a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell-v6.0/info) for PowerShell 6.

You may just have to type out the full tag name (including `-v6`) to have it pop up as a suggestion, because it only has a dozen or so questions.

Tag suggestions appear based on similarity to what you've typed so far in the tag box ordered by popularity, so currently all of the other `powershell-v` tags will show up ahead of the v6 tag.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I just need to type more :)